# Passing parameters to a BASH function

Tags: bash, troubleshooting, bash-functions

I'm trying to run FoxitReader from the command line.

For opening it, I created this function:

```
foxit(){
    /home/quora/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/FoxitReader.sh 
    }
export -f foxit
```

And put it in `.bashrc`. This would not take file names as arguments. So, `foxit mypdf.pdf` would open foxit, but not the file.

```
foxit(){
    /home/quora/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/FoxitReader.sh "$@"
    }
export -f foxit
```

On the other hand, this function would open the file(s), but not be able to save changes to it (which is the whole point of FoxitReader, this program can save highlights into pdfs.).

How can I set everything so `foxit mypdf.pdf mypdf2.pdf` would open a series of pdf files as if I had clicked on them?

Note: when I select two or more pdf files through Nautilus and press enter, Foxit is able to open, change and save changes to them.

FoxitReader.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
 appname="FoxitReader"

 selfpath="/home/d4/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader"
 exec "$selfpath/$appname" "$@"
```

Comment: Is your FoxitReader.sh script doing something special while opening foxit that's making foxit behave differently?

Comment: @JeffSchaller: I assume it's the way the arguments are passed to Foxit that screws the whole thing.

Comment: Can you share FoxitReader.sh as well? What do you mean by "not able to save changes to it", what happens if you try?

Comment: @nohillside: update with the sh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [FoxitReader manual](http://cdn01.foxitsoftware.com/pub/foxit/manual/enu/FoxitReader1.1ForLinux_Manual.pdf), it doesn't seem to allow for opening multiple files from the command line in the way you are trying to do.

If `foxitreader` is your default handler for pdf then this should work

```
#!/bin/bash
for var in "$@"
do
    xdg-open "$var"
done
```

and if it isn't the default then try

```
#!/bin/bash
for var in "$@"
do
    FoxitReader "$var" &
done
```

I don't have `foxitreader` installed to test on but it works fine with `masterpdfeditor4`